# How to capture text between XML Summary?

Tags: regex, regexbuddy

I have single-line and multi-line XML Summary texts, that look like these.

```
/// <summary> This is a single-line XML comment. </summary> 

/// <summary> This is a multi-line XML comment.
/// These are additional lines with more text.
/// Some more of these text. </summary>

/// <summary> This is another XML text summary with a different
/// format.
/// </summary>
```

In RegexBuddy, how would I capture the texts within, without the /// and the `<summary>` `</summary>` tags?

I came up with the following to capture a multi-line XML summary:

```
  ((\s*(///)\s*((<summary>)?))(.*))+(</summary>)$
```

and a single XML summary:

```
  \s*///\s*(<summary>).*(</summary>)$
```

But I've no idea how to capture just the text.

What would be the regular expression I would use, in order to capture just the text, so that I can use it in a replacement reference?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think it can be done with a single regex. I think you need to extract all the text between `<summary>` and `</summary>` and then remove the `///` strings. And don't forget the `dotall` flag for multi-line summaries. I can post a solution in java if that is appropriate and relevant.

Comment: Do you want to get the remaining text? Try replacing `^///\s*(?:<summary>\s*)?|\s*</summary>` with an empty string, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/e7MSz7/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PCRE engine:

```php
(?:^///\s*(?:<summary>)?|</summary>)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!</?summary>|^///(?!/)\s*).)+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/GchQxv/1)

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ///                      '///'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      <summary>                '<summary>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </summary>               '</summary>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (*SKIP)                     'SKIP' verb, skips the match
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (*F)                        'FAIL' verb, triggers fail and backtracking
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      <                        '<'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      /?                       '/' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      summary>                 'summary>'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ///                      '///'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        /                        '/'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (0 or more times (matching the most
                               amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-ahead
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    .                        any character except \n
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )+                       end of grouping
```